# add a new column to assign a number to a set of duplicate value in sql

Tags: sql

Please help me add new column in result like "Number" column in below table assign a number to same value and next number to another value in sequence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N24Xc.png)

```
Number  Productid   Color
1       AMC         Blue
1       AMC         Green
1       AMC         Red
2       NCR         Blue
2       NCR         Orange
3       MSO         Geen
3       MSO         Black
3       MSO         Blue
3       MSO         Yellow
```

I tried

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Productid ASC) AS Number
```

but this does not assign the same number for duplicate values.

Comment: what do you mean with "duplicate values". Duplicated what?

Comment: Try DENSE_RANK() in place of ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Thanks MatBailie. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to numerate items, and give same numbers to items with the same Productid, you could use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (...)`.

Here is example:

```sql
select
    Productid,
    Color,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Productid) num
from
    my_table
```